# How to call session from javascript which is created using code-behind with c#

Tags: javascript, c#

Hello Everyone i have created session in c# and i have to use it in Javascript it is getting error it is not bringing correct session plz help me to solve this issue

**Javascript**

```
var terminalid = '<%= Session["TerminalID"] %>';
var hospid = '<%= Session["Hospitalid"] %>';
var terminalid = '<%= Session["TerminalID"] %>';
var userid = '<%= Session["UserID"] %>';
    if (name != '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "E_Locations.aspx/AddNewLoc",
            data: "{'locname':'" + name + "','hid':'"+hospid+"','tid':'"+terminalid+"','uid':'"+userid+"'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
 }
```

**C# Code**

```
    Session["TerminalID"] = 180;

    [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public static string AddNewLoc(string locname,int hid,int tid,int uid)
    {
        string msg = string.Empty;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXECUTE S_BMD_SAVE_Location @FLAG=100, @PK_BioLocationID=0, @LocationNAME='" + locname + "', @HOSPID='" + hid + "', @TERMINALID='"+tid+"', @OPERATORID='"+uid+"'", con))
            {
                con.Open();

                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    msg = "true";
                }
                else
                {
                    msg = "false";
                }
            }
        }
        return msg;
    }
```

Comment: Is your javascript part of an aspx page?

Comment: Make an ajax call and return the session variable as json.

Comment: @mybirthname Depending on how things are laid out, that could be an expensive solution.

Comment: Short answer is you cannot because Session object is in C# and it stands on server side. While javascript is running on client side. You can try to reach session via ajax calls but there's some issue with the get that stable beacuse session expires and you must grant

Comment: server side vs. client side. you can not read server side variable from JS. Take a look at Ajax. It may help you.

Comment: @hpfs OP appears to be attempting to stamp the session ID into the JS from on the server using the `<%=... %>` syntax, which is fine, depending on where it is used.

Comment: use JSON.stringify()   to data

Comment: @Raviteja, you've edited your question, but haven't addressed any of the comments.  _Where_ is this javascript?  Also, unrelated, but right now **you are [vulnerable to SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you ...

WebForm1.aspx

```
<script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var terminalid = '1';
            var hospid = '2';
            var userid = '4';
            var obj = {};
            obj.terminalid = terminalid;
            obj.hospid = hospid;
            obj.userid = userid;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/AddNewLoc",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result.d);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static string AddNewLoc(string terminalid, string hospid, string userid)
        {
            //access session like this from backend or set sesssion value
            long TerminalID = Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Current.Session["TerminalID"]);
            //Do some stuf

            return "true";
        }
```

Comment: Thank you i got it by using

Comment: long TerminalID = Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Current.Session["TerminalID"]);   this but i have to know how to use session in jscript anyway thank u for ur help ....

Comment: call ajax to back end to get session information ....javascrript is front end language and session hold backend data..so why not use backend for backend info

Comment: Sure I ll try ...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string jsFunc = "alert(" + Session["TerminalID"] + ")";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "myJsFn", jsFunc , true);
```